# Example of a closed map which is not continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, closed-map, closed-graph

A map $F: X \to Y$ is said to be closed if $x_n \to x$ in $X$ and $F(x_n) \to y $ in $Y$ implies $y = F(x)$.

As confusing as the definition is, I cannot seem to understand how a closed map is not necessarily continuous. There is also an attached example:

Let $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given as $F(t) = 1/t$ if $t \ne 0$, and $F(0) =0$. Then $F$ is a closed map but not continuous. How?

I tried taking the sequence $t_n = 1/n$ which converges to $0$, but $F(x_n) = n$ which doesn't converge so the definition doesn't hold. I understand that I need a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n \to 0$ but $F(x_n) \to y \ne 0 = F(0)$,  but I cannot think of such a sequence.

Comment: You need to show that if $t_n$ is any sequence such that $t_n\to x$ and $F(t_n)\to y$ then $F(x)=y$. (your sequence doesn't satisfy all these requirements, so it is irrelevant) If $x\ne 0$ then this is clear, because $F$ is continuous at all nonzero points. Try to show it also holds when $x=0$.

Comment: by "definition doesn't hold" i mean that the condition $x_n \to x$ and $F(x_n) \to y$ does not hold (since $F(x_n) = n$ does not converge), so we cannot conclude whether $F$ is closed. Yes it is not continuous, but I must show it is closed first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "So the definition doesn't hold" is unclear. I would rather say "so $F$
  is not continuous at $0$".
- "I need a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n \to 0$ but $F(x_n) \to y \ne 0 = F(0)$": no, you don't. $F$ is closed because:

  - If a sequence $x_n\to x$ is eventually constant and $F(x_n)\to y\in\Bbb R,$ then $F(x)=y$ (by uniqueness of the limit). So, we only have to check the condition for sequences which are not eventually constant.
  - For $x=0$ the condition "for *every* non-eventually-constant sequence $x_n\to x$ s.t. $F(x_n)\to y   \in\Bbb R  $ we have $F(x)=y$" is [*vacuously true*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), precisely
    because there exists no such sequence (prove it).
  - For every $x\ne0$ the condition is also true, by continuity of $F$ at such a point.

Comment: okay so if such a sequence cannot exist, then $F$ is automatically closed, and it is not continuous by the argument I showed in the question. is that right?

Comment: Right. I edited to make all this more explicit.

Comment: @AnneBauval Actually, for $x=0$ there exists such a sequence, any sequence which is eventually $0$. It needs to be proved that these are the only such sequences.

Comment: @Mark thank you! I tried to correct without being too lengthy.